# VIsual select to a specific character

Tags: vim

I am working in vim. I have a piece text that looks like :

```
one = 24
two = 52
three = 56
four = 74
```

Is there a way to use visual select to yank and paste up to the equal to sign in each line ? I want an operation that leaves me with the following result :

```
one = 24
two = 52
three = 56
four = 74

one = 
two = 
three =
four =
```

My current solution is to copy the whole thing, then jump to the `one = 24` line in what I copied and then record this macro : `0f=ld$j` to @w and then repeat it three times with 3@w. Is there a way to do this using visual select and yank and paste ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use `:substitute` for these things

```
" First I yank and paste, in normal mode
yapP

" Then I transform
gv   " to reselect, while in normal mode
:s/=.*/=/   " that will actual display :'<,'>s/.....
```

The actual reselection part may need a little work depending on where the cleared snippet shall appear. May be something like `yapo<esc>p:'[,']s/=.*/=/` + enter

Answer (score 1):

You can visually select the lines to apply normal commands to them with `:norm`.

Thus, you could do:

```
ggVG:norm f=ld$
```

Comment: `d$` could become `D`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
:global /=/ copy $ | substitute /=\zs.*//
```

We use `global` to select the original lines, then `copy` them to the end `$` and remove the parts after `=` with `substitute`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mapping like this

```
vnoremap ,s y:let @"=system('sed -nE "s/=.*/=/p"',@")<cr>
```

When selecting now some lines in in visual mode, type `,s`. This will put the desired modification into the `"` register and you can paste them now using `p` wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

From anywhere on each line:

```
0vf=
```

- '0' starts your selection at the beginning of the line, so it's unneeded (but harmless) if the cursor's there already
- 'v' enters Visual mode
- 'f=' selects up to and including the first '=' on the line.